Markov chains expected quotient of visited states to unique states
Given that $n$ is a total number of states visited in a Markov process, and $m$ is a number of unique states visisted, how can I calculate $\mathbb{E}\frac{n}{m}$?
From "Finite Markov chains" by Kemeny, John G. I learned that $\mathbb{E}_in_j = N$ (here $n_j$ is a number of visits to a state $s_j$, $\mathbb{E}_i$ means that the expectation is calculated with respect to $s_i$ being the initial state, $N = (I-Q)^{-1}$ is a fundamental matrix), so I can easily calculate $\mathbb{E}n$ by summation over one of the rows of $N$.
From the book I also learned that $\mathbb{E}_im$ is $NN_{dg}^{-1}\xi$ (here $\xi$ is a vector filled with 1's), so again calculating $\mathbb{E}m$ is not a problem.
But I know that $\mathbb{E}\frac{n}{m}$ is not equal to $\frac{\mathbb{E}n}{\mathbb{E}m}$ by default (since $n$ and $m$ are dependent), I have to either prove it or invent a new formula. I tried to do so but I stumbled upon $\sum_{j=1}^{n\_states}\sum_{x \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{x}\mathbb{P}[u_j^{(k)}=1, m=x]$ (here $u_j^{(k)}$ indicates that state $s_j$ was reached at step $k$) and I can't calculate the probability inside. I ran some simulations on small chains and the difference between $\mathbb{E}\frac{n}{m}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{E}n}{\mathbb{E}m}$ has never been above 1% so the equation is not out of the question and it might be worth it to prove it... Can you give me some advice? Maybe this exact problem has already been solved and I just never heard about it?
UPD: I found a nasty example where $\mathbb{E}\frac{n}{m}$ is around $2.69$ and $\frac{\mathbb{E}n}{\mathbb{E}m} = \frac{15.726}{5.337} =$ $2.946$, the transition matrix is
[[1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1. ]
 [0.8 0.2 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.4 0.6 0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.4 0.  0.6 0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.4 0.  0.  0.6 0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.4 0.  0.2 0.2 0.2 0. ]]


If you have a total number of states visited, then presumably you stop at some point (by default, a Markov chain just goes on forever). What is your stopping condition?

@MishaLavrov I always have exactly one absorbing state. And the initial state is always known too

A simple example where $\mathbb E[n/m]$ and $\mathbb E[n]/\mathbb E[m]$ are very different is the following: $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1/k & 1-1/k \ 0 & 1 - 1/(2k^2) & 1/(2k^2) \ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$ with the first state being the starting state. Here, I get $\mathbb E[n/m] \sim \frac23 k$ and $\mathbb E[n]/\mathbb E[m] \sim k$ for large $k$.
